# Change Xubuntu to report itself as Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xubuntu

I have an installation of Xubuntu 12.04 that I want to use to run a commercial program. The commercial program runs a script at startup to check the distribution. If its supported like Ubuntu then no problem, but if it sees Xubuntu it complains about the platform. Is there a way to get Xubuntu to report its self as Ubuntu?

```
linux_dist () {
   _dist=`lsb_release -d 2> /dev/null | sed 's!^[^:]*: *!!'` 
   if [ -z "$_dist" ]; then
     if [ -f /etc/SuSE-release ]; then
       _dist=`head -n 1 /etc/SuSE-release`
     elif [ -f /etc/issue ]; then
       _dist=`head -n 1 /etc/issue`
     else
       _dist=`cat /proc/version | sed -e 's/^.*(\([^()]*Linux[^()]*\)).*$/\1/'`
     fi
   fi
   if [ -z "$_dist" ]; then _dist='unknown' ; fi
   echo $_dist
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: You probably want to ask this on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Other than that, take a look at how lsb_release works (its a Python script at least on Debian, so you can just read it).

Comment: You could just overwrite the value: `linux_dist () { _dist="Whatever you like" echo $_dist }`

Comment: Actually, since its using lsb_release, edit /etc/lsb-release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple solution:

```
sudo sed -i "s/Xubuntu/Ubuntu/g" /etc/lsb-release
```

have fun ;)